# In R for group id count days since an event but allow for more than one event per day

Tags: r, dplyr, count, grouping

```
# small data set for chess players with player id (p_id), days from some starting date (dayo)
# an Elo rating (elo) and a result win or loss (fin1_0)

p_id <- 
c(2232,1877,2210,2073,2232,2232,1877,2210,2073,2232,1877,2210,2073,1877,2232,2210,2073,2210,1877)
dayo <- c(750,750,750,750,751,750,750,750,750,751,751,751,751,751,751,751,762,762,762)
elo <- 
c(1741,1841,1651,1561,1751,1741,1841,1651,1561,1751,1851,1551,1951,1820,1660,2230,1762,1762,1762)
fin1_0 <- c(0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0)

my.df <- data.frame(p_id,elo,dayo,fin1_0)
my.df

# for each player I want to determine the number of games played, the number of wins they achieved
# the day of their last win, how many days since they won a game, how many days since they played a 
# game
# and how many games played since they won 

# what I tried
library(dplyr)

tbl.df <- my.df %>%
 # first arrange the data based on p_id and dayo
 arrange(p_id, dayo) %>%
 group_by(p_id) %>%
 mutate( games = 1:n(), 
         wins = cumsum(fin1_0 == 1) ) %>%
 # group by p_id and every win
 group_by(p_id, wins) %>%
 mutate(last_win_day = min(dayo),
 days_since_win = dayo - first(dayo) ) %>%
 group_by(p_id) %>%
 # replace the first value (or NA) in every group with a random value between 1 and 10
 mutate(days_since_win = replace(days_since_win, row_number() == 1, sample(1:10,1) ),
 days_since_game = dayo -lag(dayo),
 days_since_game = replace_na(days_since_game,sample(1:10,1))) %>%
 group_by(p_id, wins) %>%
 mutate(games_since_win = games - first(games))
 # convert back to a data.frame
 my.df <- data.frame(tbl.df)     
 my.df[order(my.df$p_id,my.df$dayo),]
 my.df

# truncated output
   p_id  elo dayo fin1_0 games wins last_win_day days_since_win days_since_game games_since_win
1  1877 1841  750      1     1    1          750             10              10               0
2  1877 1841  750      0     2    1          750              0               0               1
3  1877 1851  751      0     3    1          750              1               1               2
4  1877 1820  751      1     4    2          751              0               0               0
5  1877 1762  762      0     5    2          751             11              11               1
6  2073 1561  750      0     1    0          750              3               7               0
7  2073 1561  750      1     2    1          750              0               0               0
8  2073 1951  751      0     3    1          750              1               1               1
9  2073 1762  762      1     4    2          762              0              11               0

# wanted output
   p_id  elo dayo fin1_0 games wins last_win_day days_since_win days_since_game games_since_win
1  1877 1841  750      1     1    1          750             10              10               0
2  1877 1841  750      0     2    1          750              0               0               0
3  1877 1851  751      0     3    1          750              1               1               1
4  1877 1820  751      1     4    2          751              0               1               0
5  1877 1762  762      0     5    2          751             11              11               11
6  2073 1561  750      0     1    0          750              3               7               0
7  2073 1561  750      1     2    1          750              0               0               0
8  2073 1951  751      0     3    1          750              1               1               1
9  2073 1762  762      1     4    2          762              0              11               0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using `case_when` to track the last win day for each player. It looks like you want to show zero days since win for the first day of each player, even if they haven't won yet.

```
my.df %>%
  arrange(p_id, dayo) %>%
  group_by(p_id) %>%
  mutate( games = 1:n(), 
          wins = cumsum(fin1_0 == 1)) %>%
  mutate(day_of_last_win = case_when(
    row_number() == 1 ~ dayo,
    fin1_0 == 1       ~ dayo,
    TRUE              ~ lag(dayo)),
         days_since_last_win = dayo - day_of_last_win)
```

.

```
# A tibble: 19 x 8
# Groups:   p_id [4]
    p_id   elo  dayo fin1_0 games  wins day_of_last_win days_since_last_win
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <int> <int>           <dbl>               <dbl>
 1  1877  1841   750      1     1     1             750                   0
 2  1877  1841   750      0     2     1             750                   0
 3  1877  1851   751      0     3     1             750                   1
 4  1877  1820   751      1     4     2             751                   0
 5  1877  1762   762      0     5     2             751                  11
 6  2073  1561   750      0     1     0             750                   0
 7  2073  1561   750      1     2     1             750                   0
 8  2073  1951   751      0     3     1             750                   1
 9  2073  1762   762      1     4     2             762                   0
10  2210  1651   750      0     1     0             750                   0
11  2210  1651   750      0     2     0             750                   0
12  2210  1551   751      0     3     0             750                   1
13  2210  2230   751      0     4     0             751                   0
14  2210  1762   762      0     5     0             751                  11
15  2232  1741   750      0     1     0             750                   0
16  2232  1741   750      0     2     0             750                   0
17  2232  1751   751      1     3     1             751                   0
18  2232  1751   751      1     4     2             751                   0
19  2232  1660   751      0     5     2             751                   0
```

Comment: Your answer was useful, drew my attention to the function case_when. I am still puzzled how to get days_since_game (ie days_since_last_game) and games_since_win (ie games_since_last_win). I am trying to use these features to assess the "form" of a player: they may not have played for a while or may not have won for a while.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? I'm not sure I understand what you're still looking for.

Comment: Sorry Jon, my bad!  I am trying to model chess player performance, however the model could apply to other competitive events, markets etc.  Each row represents the result of a game from the point of view of one game played. I start with data over time with a player id, a day, an Elo rating and the result as 1:0 ie win or loss. I want to create some features that may or may not be useful in a model. Like number of games played (would equate to experience), number of games won (may equate to ability), how recently were games played (may equate to the player being "rusty")

Comment: Continuing, how recently were wins (may indicate the player was in good form). A complication may arise if more than one game was played on the same day. Here the relevant indicator is not the most recent game if it was played on the same day. For example if a player had not played for a month then played two games on the same day then BOTH games would be treated from the player's point of view of being played after an absence of a month. Does this make sense?